# @ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestContext.class, WebAppContext.class}) Entrega un Error: WebAppContext cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, spring

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import org.springframework.web.*;

import com.example.demo.persistence.UsuarioDAO;
import com.example.demo.transferobject.UsuarioTO;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.model;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestContext.class, WebAppContext.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class FamaciaControllerTest {
     private UsuarioTO user1,user2;
      private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Autowired
        private UsuarioDAO usuarioDAOMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        user1 = new UsuarioTO();
        user1.setNombre("Remigio");
        user1.setRut("18789533-5");

        user2 = new UsuarioTO();
        user2.setNombre("Remi");
        user2.setRut("18789423-5");



    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAllUsers() throws Exception  {


            when(usuarioDAOMock.readAll()).thenReturn((LinkedList<UsuarioTO>) Arrays.asList(user1, user2));

            mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(view().name("ver-usuarios.jsp"))
                    .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/jsp/todo/list.jsp"))
                    .andExpect(model().attribute("list", hasSize(2)))
                    .andExpect(model().attribute("list", hasItem(
                            allOf(
                                    hasProperty("idUsuario", is(1)),
                                    hasProperty("nombre", is("Remigio")),
                                    hasProperty("rut", is("18789533-5"))
                            )
                    )))
                    .andExpect(model().attribute("todos", hasItem(
                            allOf(
                                    hasProperty("idUsuario", is(2)),
                                    hasProperty("nombre", is("Remi")),
                                    hasProperty("rut", is("18789423-5"))
                            )
                    )));

            verify(usuarioDAOMock, times(1)).readAll();
            verifyNoMoreInteractions(usuarioDAOMock);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: En ningún lado esta el import de `WebAppContext.class` y me parece que no esta en el mismo paquete que tu clase.